# How do I ensure that alphaStr does not generate empty strings?

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I am using the ScalaCheck generator `alphaStr` to generate Strings but they always come back empty. For eg. the following test fails on the first string.

```
class GenSpec extends FunSuite with GeneratorDrivenPropertyChecks with Matchers {
  implicit val noShrink: Shrink[List[Char]] = Shrink.shrinkAny
  test("alphaStr") {
    forAll(Gen.alphaStr) { case str =>
      println(str)
      str.isEmpty shouldBe false
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
TestFailedException was thrown during property evaluation.
  Message: true was not equal to false
  Location: (GenSpec.scala:12)
  Occurred when passed generated values (
    arg0 = ""
  )
ScalaTestFailureLocation: org.scalatest.prop.GeneratorDrivenPropertyChecks$class at (GeneratorDrivenPropertyChecks.scala:914)
org.scalatest.exceptions.GeneratorDrivenPropertyCheckFailedException: TestFailedException was thrown during property evaluation.
  Message: true was not equal to false
  Location: (GenSpec.scala:12)
  Occurred when passed generated values (
    arg0 = ""
  )
```

I have added `noShrink` to ensure that the underlying list of chars does not get shrunk. But it still fails. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure that shrink will work in this case and `alphaStr` doesn't concern itself with empty values but as alternative you can use `filter` and the string length:

```
Gen.alphaStr.filter(_.trim.length > 0)
```

Comment: An alternative is `Gen.alphaStr.suchThat(_.nonEmpty)` but I was wondering why does it generate an empty string a the first value.

Answer (score 1):

`Gen.alphaStr.suchThat(_.nonEmpty)` perfectly works, but sometimes its `sample` might generate `None` (indeed when the original `alphaStr` generator was the empty string). This is sometimes not desirable.

An alternative is concatenating the results of `Gen.alphaChar` and `Gen.alphaStr`, like this:

```
Gen.zip(Gen.alphaChar, Gen.alphaStr).map(t => t._1 + t._2)
```